# Jquery table not displaying added rows

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table that stores information for ordering paper. The user can add and delete rows before submitting their order. Before finally sending their order, a user can reopen their current order to check that everything they entered is right etc. The issue i am having is that when the user goes back to check their order, if more than one paper is selected, only the first row is displayed. Does anyone know why that is and how it can be resolved?

**JQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $counter = 1;
    $('#buttonadd').click(function () {
        $counter++;
        $('#invoiceitems > tbody:last').append('<tr><td><input type="button" class="buttondelete" value="Delete"/></td>\
        <td><input type="text" name="product_code_' + $counter + '" id="product_code_' + $counter + '" class="product_code" size="20" maxlength="70" value="" /></td>\
        <td><input type="text" name="description_' + $counter + '" id="description_' + $counter + '" class="description" size="85" maxlength="70" value="" /></td>\
        <td><input type="text" name="priceper_' + $counter + '" id="priceper_' + $counter + '" class="priceper" size="10" maxlength="9" value="" /></td>\
        <td><input type="text" name="per_pack_' + $counter + '" id="per_pack_' + $counter + '" class="per_pack" size="10" maxlength="9" value="" /></td>\
        <td><input type="text" name="pack_qty_' + $counter + '" id="pack_qty_' + $counter + '" class="pack_qty" size="10" maxlength="9" value="" /></td>\
    <td><input type="text" name="quantity_' + $counter + '" id="quantity_' + $counter + '" class="quantity" size="10" maxlength="9" value="" /></td>\
        <td><input type="text" id="subtotal_' + $counter + '" name="quantity_' + $counter + '" class="subtotal" size="10" maxlength="9" /></td></tr>');
    window.globalVar = $counter;

    });
    $('table#invoiceitems').on('keyup', '.quantity , .priceper',function () {
        UpdateTotals(this);
    });

    $counter = 1;
       $('table#invoiceitems').on('click','.buttondelete',function () {
        $counter++;
        if($('table#invoiceitems tbody tr').length==1){
            alert('Cant delete single row');
            return false;
        }
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    UpdateTotals(this);

    });
    CalculateSubTotals();
    CalculateTotal();
});


function UpdateTotals(elem) {
    // This will give the tr of the Element Which was changed
    var $container = $(elem).parent().parent();
    var quantity = $container.find('.quantity').val();
    var price = $container.find('.priceper').val();
    var per_pack = $container.find('.per_pack').val();
    var subtotal = parseInt(quantity) * parseFloat(price) / parseInt(per_pack);

    $container.find('.subtotal').val(subtotal.toFixed(2));
    CalculateTotal();
}

function CalculateSubTotals() {
    // Calculate the Subtotals when page loads for the 
    // first time
    var lineTotals = $('.subtotal');
    var quantity = $('.quantity');
    var price = $('.priceper');
    var per_pack = $('.per_pack');
    $.each(lineTotals, function (i) {
        var tot = parseInt($(quantity[i]).val()) * parseFloat($(price[i]).val()) / parseInt($(per_pack[i]).val());
     if (isNaN(val) || val === undefined) {
            return;
        }
        $(lineTotals[i]).val(tot.toFixed(2));
    });
}

function CalculateTotal() {
    // This will Itearate thru the subtotals and
    // claculate the grandTotal and Quantity here
    var lineTotals = $('.subtotal');
    var quantityTotal = $('.quantity');
    var grandTotal = 0.0;
    var totalQuantity = 0;
    $.each(lineTotals, function (i) {
        grandTotal += parseFloat($(lineTotals[i]).val());
        totalQuantity += parseInt($(quantityTotal[i]).val())
    });
    $('.totalquantity').val(totalQuantity);
    $('.total').val(parseFloat(grandTotal).toFixed(2));
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<table border="0" id="invoiceitems">
                            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                                    <td><strong>Product Code</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Description</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Price</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Per</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Pack Qty</strong></td>  
                    <td><strong>Quantity</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Subtotal</strong></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>

        </tfoot>
                            <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="button" class="buttondelete" value="Delete" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="product_code_0" id="product_code_0" class="product_code" size="20" maxlength="9" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($product_code[0]);?>"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="description_0" id="description_0" class="regular-text" size="85" maxlength="70" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($description[0]); ?>" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="priceper_0" id="priceper_0" class="priceper" size="10" maxlength="9" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($priceper[0]); ?>" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="per_pack_0" id="per_pack_0" class="per_pack" size="10" maxlength="9" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($per_pack[0]); ?>" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="pack_qty_0" id="pack_qty_0" class="pack_qty" size="10" maxlength="9" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($pack_qty[0]); ?>" /></td> 
            <td><input type="text" name="quantity_0" id="quantity_0" class="quantity" size="10" maxlength="9" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($quantity[0]); ?>" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="subtotal_0" id="subtotal_0" class="subtotal" size="10" maxlength="9" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($subtotal[0]); ?>" /></td></tr>
        </tbody> 
        </table>
        <p><input type="button" id="buttonadd" value="Add Line" /></p>
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'a user can reopen their current order'? Are they navigating away from the current page?

Comment: @ReinderWit Yes. When the user submits their order, they are directed back to the page which shows the summary of orders